# How to implement google map autocomplete for suburbs and surrounding suburbs - flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps

I need to implement a Textfield with autocomplete to search and add suburbs in my app, I also need to implement an option to include surrounding suburbs as well. There are lots of APIs in google map service and I don't know which one I will need to implement these.
which API should I use and with which package I can implement what I need in flutter?

Comment: Please note that this type of question is not acceptable in Stack Overflow. Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to know more. But to help you as best effort, you can check out https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter